# Jupyter error Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions

Tags: installation, jupyter

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defusedxml-0.6.0.dist-info'

Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

```
pip install --user jupyter
```

the above command doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I faced sam issue trying to upgrade **pip**.
I wasn't been able to do that with:

```
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

But it run ok with:

```
!python -m pip install --upgrade --user pip
```

**For installing Jupyter Notebook**
try using:

```
pip install --user notebook
```

instead of:

```
pip install notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access you can try:

```
sudo pip install jupyter
```

Comment: Does that work for Centos and Ubuntu based systems?

Comment: Yes, it should!